# Overlapping printing of an IEnumerable collection

Tags: c#, printing, ienumerable

I'm reading the contents of an XML file into an IEnumerable collection (array) and I need to print each iteration (block of like XML data) on a separate page.

I'm using the Print() function and e.HasMorePages.  My problem is that the foreach loops through all iterations of the IEnumerable collection for each print so I'm printing the correct number of pages but each page contains all iterations on top of each other instead of one per page.  Can anyone give me an idea for a solution or a better way to manage this process?

Here's the pertinent portion of the code...

```
// Print Employee General info
        foreach (EmployeeInfo itm in GEmployeeXGD.GetEmployeeGeneralData())
        {
            try
            {
                empFirstName = itm.FirstName;
                empLastName = itm.LastName;
                empMidInitial = itm.MidInitial;
        etc…

                // Set field coordinates for each employee
                // ******* Employee's general information ********
                PointF empFirstNameLoc = new PointF(430, 271);
                PointF empLastNameLoc = new PointF(600, 271);
                PointF empMidInitialLoc = new PointF(563, 271);
        etc…
                // Send field text data
                using (Font courierFont = new Font("Courier", 10, FontStyle.Bold))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(empFirstName, courierFont, Brushes.Black, empFirstNameLoc);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(empLastName, courierFont, Brushes.Black, empLastNameLoc);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(empMidInitial, courierFont, Brushes.Black, empMidInitialLoc);
        etc…
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error) { MessageBox.Show(error.ToString()); }
            e.HasMorePages = (records < Globals.totalRecordCount);
        }
```

That's helpful Joel, thanks.

GEmployeeXGD reverences a class with a single method.  The method reads in the XML data that I need and populates the IEnumerable<> collection as an array.  Here's the method..

```
        public Array GetEmployeeGeneralData()
    {
        // XML source file
        var xmlEmployeeFile = File.ReadAllText("Corrections.xml");
        XDocument employeeDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlEmployeeFile);
        XElement w2cEmployeeDat = employeeDoc.Element("CorrectedDAta");
        EmployeeInfo[] employeeGenInfo = null;
        if (w2cEmployeeDat != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<XElement> employeeRecords = w2cEmployeeDat.Elements("Employee");
            try
            {
                employeeGenInfo = (from itm in employeeRecords
                                   select new EmployeeInfo()
                                   {
                                       FirstName = (itm.Element("FirstName") != null) ? itm.Element("FirstName").Value : string.Empty,
                                       LastName = (itm.Element("LastName") != null) ? itm.Element("LastName").Value : string.Empty,
                                       MidInitial = (itm.Element("MidInitial") != null) ? itm.Element("MidInitial").Value : string.Empty,
            etc…
                                   }).ToArray<EmployeeInfo>();
            }
            catch (Exception) { MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());  }
        }
        Globals.SetRecordCount(employeeGenInfo.Count<EmployeeInfo>());
        recordCount = Globals.totalRecordCount;

        return employeeGenInfo;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of what page you are on, and then do something like this:

```
var items = GEmployeeXGD.GetEmployeeGeneralData().Skip( (pageNumber-1) * numberItemsPerPage).Take(numberOfItemsPerPage); 
foreach (EmployeeInfo itm in items)
{
    //...
}
```

Even better if you can avoid calling that same method over and over, and keep the same IEnumerable across individual pages. But to demonstrate this, I'd need to see more of the context of the class where this method lives, and know more about how `GEmployeeXGD` works.

Comment: Skip isn't available for GEmployeeXGD.GetEmployeeGeneralData().  If I assign as indicated (  var items = GEmployeeXGD.GetEmployeeGeneralData();  ) then items contains all array elements of collections (i.e employeeInfo[0], employeeInfo[1], etc).  Is there a way to index these elements so that the foreach uses only one at a time?